# How can i get JavaFX working on raspberry pi 3

Tags: java, javafx, arm, raspberry-pi3, javafxports

please can someone provide me with simple step by step instructions for getting javafx working on raspberry pi 3. I have tried all day to add javafx to raspberry pi 3 and i am still getting the error:

"JavaFX deployment library not found in the active JDK"

in netbeans when i try to build, even though there are no errors showing in my code.

I downloaded the gluon community build for javaFX embedded sdk here: http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/downloads/
and followed the instructions here: http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/

please can anyone offer any easy to follow advice on getting javaFX working on raspberry pi 3! i am quite new to linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have read the documentation [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#anchor-1), under 2.1.4 Prerequisites for Embedded:

1. Download the latest version of JDK 8 for ARM to your embedded device, available from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). You will have to download this file: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u91-b14/jdk-8u91-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz

You can download it to your computer first, and then move it to the Pi, or directly download it from the Raspberry Pi, unzip and install.

2. Download the latest version of the JavaFX Embedded SDK port, available [here](http://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-embedded-sdk/), and copy to your Pi. Unzip the downloaded JavaFX Embedded SDK and copy the following files into the JDK 8 installation directory:

   - armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar  -->  jre/lib/ext/
   - armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/arm/*  --> jre/lib/arm/
   - armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.platform.properties --> jre/lib/
   - armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.properties --> jre/lib/
   - armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/jfxswt.jar  --> jre/lib/

You can deploy JavaFX projects on your Pi directly copying them from your computer, or using the remote deployment available with NetBeans (Remote Platform) or with the Gluon Plugin for your IDE.

For a short guide on creating a remote platform on NetBeans, check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/nb-8-raspberry-pi-end2end). For the Gluon Plugin, check these [settings](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_embedded_3).

Comment: Thanks, i had already read and followed the instructions above, but was still having problems running from the platform independent version on Netbeans installled on my Pi. After setting up remote deployment following the guide you posted, and running it from my pc it is now working

Comment: Thanks, was missing the JavaFX Embedded SDK ! No other site linked it :(